# Wifi Csi Using TinyML in Esp32

Tags: esp32, csi, tinyml

I am just working on the wifi csi for the person detection in my home using ESP32. Is there any tinyml model (already available) to use for my project? If yes can someone send me the links?

Links for the tinyml pre trained model